# Flexbox not vertically centering inline-block spans

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a dashboard I am setting up that has wrapper blocks with a sprite icon that should be centered vertically and horizontally inside its parent.

I got the blocks to be placed how I want and wrapping how I want using flexbox.

I also have the icon centered horizontally using the `text-align` property, but for some reason `justify-content: center` doesn't do anything when I add it to the `.view` or `.sprite-icon` elements; adding it to the `.views` element also doesn't center things how I want and it breaks the padding between the `.view` blocks.

See my JSFiddle I set up showing the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/efarley/k0m4nxny/

```css
.views {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.view {
  height: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 105px;
}
.sprite-icon {
  background-image: url('http://67.media.tumblr.com/b2336d673e315081b6d657f8258c313d/tumblr_mv98xzSiJu1qhori9o1_500.jpg');
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}
.sprite-icon.one {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.sprite-icon.two {
  background-position: 0 35px;
}
.sprite-icon.three {
  background-position: 0 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class='views'>
  <div class='view'>
    <span class='sprite-icon one'></span>
  </div>
  <div class='view'>
    <span class='sprite-icon two'></span>
  </div>
  <div class='view'>
    <span class='sprite-icon three'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `view` a flex container, then add flex centering properties.

```
.view {
  height: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 105px;
  display: flex;             /* new */
  align-items: center;       /* new */
  justify-content: center;   /* new */
}
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0m4nxny/1/)

*Note that the `justify-content` property only applies to flex containers. In your question, you were applying it to a flex item. That's why it failed.*

Learn more about flex centering:

- [How to Center Elements Vertically and Horizontally in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings:

```
.sprite-icon {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px auto;
  background-image: url('http://67.media.tumblr.com/b2336d673e315081b6d657f8258c313d/tumblr_mv98xzSiJu1qhori9o1_500.jpg');
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}
```

`margin 35px auto` centers it horzontally (when `position` is `relative`) and moves it down 35px, which centers it vertically, but only since `display` is now `block`. I erased `text-align: center` in `.view`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0t4vbzxb/1/

Comment: I'm trying to use flexbox for this so the centering is flexible and not hard coded incase the design changes over time.

Comment: flexbox only affects the direct children of the flex container i.e. `.view`, and only block elements, so it doesn't do anything on your `span` elements It still distributes the `view`elements evenly, though, in which i centered the `sprite-icon`s